# AppBar with top (vertical) drawer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make drawer coming from bottom of the AppBar. This is where I get so far

```
  double height = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Drawer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('press'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                height == 5 ? height = 150 : height = 5;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedContainer(
            color: Colors.green,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            height: height,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[Text('hello')],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

It works somehow ok however this solution moves the bottom container with it and I need that drawer to be behind it or in other words expand on top of the red container. Another problem is that when you place `Column` with some children in the animated container then the content overflow. The best solution would be to move that drawer behind the AppBar instead of changing size I guess

[image]

Here is how I tried to fixed overflowing but it didn't work

```
AnimatedContainer(
            color: Colors.green,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            height: height,
            child: height == 5
                ? Container(color: Colors.green)
                : Column(
                    children: <Widget>[Text('hello')],
                  ),
          )
```

Comment: What if instead the `Column` , `Stack` is used ?

Comment: @dev-aentgs I tried to play with the stack and replacing Column with stack makes Animated Container disappear. You can try it.. I've made simple reproducible code in my question..

Comment: If the order is changed the last widget in the `Stack` will be on the Top.  will try out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this just change column widget to stack widget and interchange the position of the container and animated container in the code.

```
double height = 5;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Drawer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('press'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                height == 5 ? height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height : height = 5;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          AnimatedContainer(
            color: Colors.green,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            height: height,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[Text('hello')],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
```

Comment: great that fixed one thing but still the overflowing is there. If you replace ListView with column and some children in AnimatedContainer then it overflows. I placed the list view there just to make it work

Comment: Its overflowing because of fixed final height given to the AnimatedContainer. Can you add some picture or a bit more detail about the end result ? @delmin

Comment: you can also use scrollview to avoid the overflow

Comment: @dev-aentgs end result will have some control visuals for filter there like buttons radio buttons sliders and check boxes.. This solution even if it works visually will not work with widgets in it.. I have updated my question with what I tried.

Comment: @delmin `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` can be used to prevent scrolling

Comment: @Niteesh Yes that is one way of doing it but I don't want that content of the drawer to scroll or have any scroll interaction of the content. In the perfect world it should act like a build in drawer sliding out from the AppBar

Comment: @Niteesh yes... I forgot about that... Hold on let me try it

Comment: @delmin use `height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to set the max height.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the code by @delmin and @niteesh, added `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` and `height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

```
class AnimatedDrawerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedDrawerDemoState createState() => _AnimatedDrawerDemoState();
}

class _AnimatedDrawerDemoState extends State<AnimatedDrawerDemo> {
  double height = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Drawer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('press'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                height == 5
                    ? height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                    : height = 5;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          AnimatedContainer(
            color: Colors.green,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            height: height,
            child: ListView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Text('Drawer Header'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item 1'),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    //Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm It actually does work. Something about it just doesn't feel right but it works... I will close this question as answered then.. Just to be fair I will mark the first answer as answered. Sorry for that

Comment: Dont have to apologize @delmin , much deserved.  If you come up with a proper way to do this, update the question with your approach in future.